# hover on 'a' tags (IE not working properly)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover

We have a `div` with `a` tags. There is a `hover` style defined in `css`.  All works fine except in IE. 
Open [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BqjSa/) (in IE) please, and try to move the mouse between `div` with time. As you can see the first `div` changes color. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Bug was reproducable in IE8. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: table;` and replace with `overflow: hidden;` in `#kassa_cont_space .sean_box .details .sched`, which is the very last style in the CSS.

```
#kassa_cont_space .sean_box .details .sched {
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqjSa/4/

Answer (score 1):

change this part of your code ...

```
<div class="sched">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001"><span class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div>
```

.. to this..

```
<div class="sched">
<div style="float:left; margin:0;padding:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span    class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div>
   <div style="float:left; margin:0;padding:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span    class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div><div style="float:left; margin:0;padding:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span    class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div><div style="float:left; margin:0;padding:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span    class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div><div style="float:left; margin:0;padding:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link _001" style = "display:block;"><span    class="time">10:30</span><span class="cost">от 700 тг</span></a>
</div>
    </div>
```

this will solve your problem...

or just remove "display:table" from  "#kassa_cont_space .sean_box .details .sched" css